# scroll to coordinates of draggable object based on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hopefully I can get some help here. I want to scroll to and center on an element inside a draggable object (jqueryUI), so that no matter where the draggable object is in its parent, it would scroll to the location of this specific child. Here is some of the html

```
<div class="widget-container">
    <div class="widget-map-elements">
        <span id="group1">•</span>
        <img src="img/draggable.jpg" width="768" height="566" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>

<p class="show-first">
    <a class="scrollme" href="#group1">center first observations</a>
</p>
```

And the jquery I have so far (incorrectly centering on the hash) is:

```
$( ".widget-map-elements" ).draggable();

$(".scrollme").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var offsetTop = $(this.hash).offset().top - $(".widget-container").offset().top;
    var offsetLeft = $(this.hash).offset().left - $(".widget-container").offset().left;
    $( ".widget-map-elements" ).animate({ top: offsetTop / 2, left: offsetLeft / 2 }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });    
});
```

Comment: This question is a little unclear. If I read this right, you want the parent objects viewport to center on the drag'd item position when it stops?

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zj48e3bL/ not able to really see the issue with this small example.

Comment: Wonder if you are trying something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zj48e3bL/3/

Comment: not quite. What I'm trying to accomplish here is more along the lines of if your 'pointer' div was embedded in the div containing the map, and that whole div was draggable. And then no matter where that div was dragged about on stage, to be able to center it based on the location of that pointer element so that it snaps into center. make any more sense?

Comment: Not really. Could just keep 'pointer' in center and move the map underneath it.

Comment: pointer is a coordinate on the map. so they need to move together